# Connecting multiple "additional" monitors to duplicate displays from multiple computers

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, desktop-computer

I have two desktop computers in Room 1, each of which have 2 monitors connected to them (1x VGA, 1x HDMI, each). These 2 monitors are dedicated to the individual computer they are attached to, and are used "normally".

In Room 2, I have a single large monitor. I want to have the single monitor in Room 2 connected to both desktops in Room 1 in a manner that allows me to click a button, flip a switch, do a jig, whatever is necessary in order to duplicate a display onto the monitor in Room 2. Let's say the first desktop in Room 1 has monitors A and B, and the second desktop has monitors C and D. I am imagining a box "switch" of some sort that has 4 buttons, labeled A-D. When I press A, the monitor in Room 2 duplicates the display from Room 1's first desktop Monitor A. When I press the B button on the switch, the Room 2 monitor changes to duplicate B. And so on.

1) How can I accomplish this? What kind of hardware or software is necessary, and how do the monitors need to be connected and/or configured?

2) What if I also had Room 3, with the exact same setup as Room 2. Maybe I want Monitor A duplicated in Room 2, but Monitor B duplicated in Room 3. Or perhaps I want both Room 2 and Room 3 to duplicate Monitor C. How does this additional "standalone" monitor change the setup, if at all?

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question. Hardware-Software recommendations are off topic here also.

Comment: So far the best option I have found is a 4-to-1 HDMI switch. All 4 outputs from the 2 desktops would be split, one going to the primary monitor and one going to the 4-to-1 switch. That switch has a single output that goes to the 3rd monitor in room 2/3. This will just be a bit cumbersome, and it is not a scalable solution. I'm not looking for specific products, just a concept, such as me saying 4-to-1 HDMI switch.

Comment: You just need a combination of HDMI splitters and HDMI switches. For splitters look for externally powered or amplified models. Check Amazon, I did something like this with all off the shelf parts.

Comment: Another hint on HDMI splitters.. All monitors must be in the same resolution, you can't get 1080i if any single monitor attached only supports 720p etc.